# Data not populating from the SQL Server when deployed to the web server but works fine on the localhost

Tags: asp.net, web-config, connection-string, sqlconnection

I have an asp.net web app app which runs perfectly fine on my localhost but the data is not populating on the page when I copied the same source to the web server. I tried both Windows and SQL Server authentication. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This is my `web.config` connection

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="myKey" 
         value="Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated security=SSPI;User ID=UserID; Password=Password;" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: are you sure that your web server is able to connect to database? Most databases have a firewall allowing only certain ip's to connect to them.

Comment: You should use the `<connectionStrings>` section in `web.config`

Comment: @It'satrap I'am not sure if a firewall is blocking, could you please tell me how would i figure that out?

Comment: @marc_s i have used connection string as  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ProjectName-20160928215159;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ProjectName-20160928215159.mdf" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: Type ping ServerName in command prompt on your production server. If that DNS doesn't exist, you may find out SQL server's IP address and replace "ServerName" with that IP.

Comment: That will depend on where you have hosted your db. If it is with aws, you can just check and add a security group rule. Can you share details where you have hosted the database and application server?

Comment: @JonasT thank you, i replaced IP address of SQL server with server name but that does not seem to help

Comment: @It'satrap my db and app source are hosted on two different servers and i have full access to both of them. i work remote and we usually put our source on the web server and never had such issues before.

Comment: @Krish. Something is wrong with your Server name field. Which server name do you use when you connect your live SQL server via SQL server management studio? Let's say your SQL server IP is 123.123.123.123/sqldb, replace the server name in connection string what you use there.

Comment: Then try to ping the server as Jonas said in the 3'rd comment. If you are able to get a response, it's your connection string's fault. If you don't get, you have firewall issues.